# pass ViewBag to js function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I am having a dropdown list in which I call a js function, on change event.
In View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RaceId", ViewData["Races"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value)", @class="form-control" })
```

and my js:

```
<script>
function CallChangefunc(val) 
{ 
//called in Index page when dropdown list changes
 window.location.href = "/Index/" + val;
}
</script>
```

What I want is to add a new argument to my js function where I pass a ViewBag value, sth like:

```
@Html.DropDownList("RaceId", ViewData["Races"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @onchange = "CallChangefunc(this.value,ViewBag.id)", @class="form-control" })
```

The above does not work and I am not sure which is the correct syntax, if any.

Comment: Use [unobtrusive javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (its the 21st century) - `$(#RaceId').change(function() { var val = $(this).val(); var id = '@ViewBag.id'; ...... });`

Comment: @stephenmuecke's comment requires jQuery and should read $('#RaceId') ..... But he makes a good point!

Answer (score 0):

First, use `unobtrusive javascript` instead of `onchange attribute`. If you have your javascript inside your view, you can access `ViewBag` too, using `'@ViewBag'`:

```
$('#RaceId').on('change', function() 
    { 
        var value = $(this).val(); 
        var id = '@ViewBag.id'
    }
);
```

Or if you're running your javascript on a different file, you can use a `Hidden input` and get this value in your script:

```
@Html.Hidden("Id", ViewBag.id)
```

and in you script:

```
$('#RaceId').on('change', function() 
    { 
        var value = $(this).val(); 
        var id = $("Id").val();
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Stephen's comment is 100% correct, i would just like to know if this solves your problem:

```
 @{
    var htmlAttr = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    htmlAttr.Add("onchange", string.Format("{0}{1})", "CallChangefunc(this.value", @ViewBag.id));
                    htmlAttr.Add("class", "form-control");
  }
  @Html.DropDownList("RaceId", ViewData["Races"] as List<SelectListItem>, @htmlAttr)
```